# Evitar sobreponer imagen encima de menú

Tags: html, css

Tengo una serie de imágenes con transiciones que se me sobreponen sobre el menú y no las puedo mantener estáticas. ¿Me pueden ayudar?

```css
@keyframes display {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.pic-ctn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px 3px #ccc;
    background-color:#feebed;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    max-width: 1180px;
}

.pic-ctn > img {

  opacity: 0;
  animation: display 15s infinite;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
```

```html
                    <!--        IMG         -->
<div class="pic-ctn">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=1" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=2" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=3" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=4" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=5" alt="" class="pic">
 </div>
        <!--        IMG         -->
```

---

```css
@keyframes display {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.pic-ctn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px 3px #ccc;
    background-color:#feebed;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    max-width: 1180px;
    overflow: hidden; /* Hidden en particular permite que los elementos que se están saliendo del DIV padre no se vean. En otras palabras, haces que los elementos internos respeten el tamaño del Contenedor (div) en el que se encuentran. */
}

.pic-ctn > img {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: display 15s infinite;
  
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="logo-place"><a href="index.php"><img src="assets/logo.png"></a></div>
    <div class="search-place">
        <input type="text" id="idbusqueda" placeholder="Encuenta lo que necesitas..." value="">
        <button class="btn-main btn-search" onclick="search_producto()"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="options-place">
        <div class="item-option" title="Ingresar">
            <a href="login.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-option" title="Mis compras">
            <a href="carrito.php"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-movil">
        <div class="item-option" onclick="mostrar_opciones()"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</header>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mostrar_opciones(){
        if (document.getElementById("ctrl-menu").style.display=="none") {
            document.getElementById("ctrl-menu").style.display="block";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("ctrl-menu").style.display="none";
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="menu-opciones" id="ctrl-menu" style="display: none;">   
    
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="carrito.php">
                <div class="menu-opcion">Carrito</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="historial.php">
                <div class="menu-opcion">Historial de compras</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="pedido.php">
                <div class="menu-opcion">Pedidos por pagar</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="_logout.php">
                <div class="menu-opcion">Salir</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="login.php">
                <div class="menu-opcion">Iniciar sessión</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="carrito.php">
                <div class="menu-opcion">Carrito</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="content-page">
                    <!--        IMG         -->
<div class="pic-ctn">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=1" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=2" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=3" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=4" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=5" alt="" class="pic">
 </div>
        <!--        IMG         -->
```

**Son muchos archivos te dejo foto de como se ve**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad **Overflow** te puede ayudar con este problema, **Hidden** en particular permite que los elementos que se están saliendo del **Div** padre no se vean. En otras palabras, haces que los elementos internos respeten el tamaño del **Contenedor** (div) en el que se encuentran.

Te recomiendo que estudies los atributos de **Overflow**, como **Hidden**, **Auto**, etc. (Es muy útil para el CSS ;D)

```css
@keyframes display {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.pic-ctn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px 3px #ccc;
    background-color:#feebed;
    font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    max-width: 1180px;
    overflow: hidden; /* Hidden en particular permite que los elementos que se están saliendo del DIV padre no se vean. En otras palabras, haces que los elementos internos respeten el tamaño del Contenedor (div) en el que se encuentran. */
}

.pic-ctn > img {

  opacity: 0;
  animation: display 15s infinite;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
```

```html
                    <!--        IMG         -->
<div class="pic-ctn">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=1" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=2" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=3" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=4" alt="" class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?t=5" alt="" class="pic">
 </div>
        <!--        IMG         -->
```

Comment: Lee [answer]: puede que la respuesta sea útil para el OP, pero es necesario que expliques brevemente _qué hace el código_.

Comment: Lo he comentado junto a la propiedad Overflow en el CSS, no es suficiente con eso? (pregunta sería xD)

Comment: No está mal de hecho; de todas maneras, es bueno indicar que las aclaraciones están en los comentarios del código (ya que puede que otros usuarios más adelante tampoco lo noten a simple vista).

Comment: Bueno, tienes razón. Editaré la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con lo que me ayudaste ya no me sobrepone el fondo rosa pero si las imagenes aun, investigare mas al respecto Overflow porque debe haber algo malo

Comment: Creo que no entendí que era lo que buscabas exactamente. Podrías compartir más de tu código y explicar con exactitud cuales son los problemas? =D

Comment: Deja ver si puedo enviar mas código o fotos, soy nuevo en esta web.